# Accessing a Kotlin object nested in companion object from Java

Tags: java, object, kotlin, kotlin-companion

I have a structure like this in Kotlin

```
companion object Constants {
    /**
     * Collection of fields and values relative to phone books.
     */
    object PhoneBooks {
        /**
         * Field indicating the ID of a phone book.
         * Each phone book must have an unique ID.
         */
        const val PB_ID_KEY = "PB_ID"

        /**
         * Field indicating the status of phone book.
         */
        const val PB_STATUS_KEY = "PB_Status"

        /**
         * One of the possible [PB_STATUS_KEY] values, when the phone book is in indexing state
         * (usually at startup or in update phase).
         */
        const val PB_INDEXING = "Indexing"
        [...]
```

The problem is that I must have the possibility to access the constants' values in sub-objects from Java, but it seems not possible. How can I solve that without changing the structure?

Comment: Works fine here using `import static com.yourcompany.yourproject.YourClass.Constants.PhoneBooks;`, and then `PhoneBooks.PB_ID_KEY`.

Comment: Change in an answer if you want some rep!

Comment: I don't care about rep. And I would be happy to see a more elaborate answer, from someone with more knowledge than me. But at least my comment unblocks you.

Comment: Anyways, thank you so much. I think that also a not-so-much elaborated answer can unblock many other people ;)

Comment: It doesn't works outside application packages...

Comment: By "scratch file" do you mean https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scratches.html? If it doesn't work there, it may be an IDE bug...

Comment: yes exactly... I must verify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991461/accessing-a-kotlin-object-nested-in-companion-object-from-java#comment104234617_58991461) commented:

> Works fine here using
>
> `import static com.yourcompany.yourproject.YourClass.Constants.PhoneBooks;`
>
> and then
>
> `PhoneBooks.PB_ID_KEY`

It works very good for me! So I think it's useful to make it visible as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments above  JB Nizet  shows how to solve the issue with a static import

However Looking at the provided code I would use an Enum

```
// kotlin
enum class PhoneBooks(val param:String) {
    PB_ID_KEY("PB_ID"),
    PB_STATUS_KEY("PB_Status"),
    PB_INDEXING("Indexing")

}

// java
System.out.println(PhoneBooks.PB_ID_KEY.getParam());
```

A big advantage here is code readability
PhoneBooks.PB_ID_KEY flags PB_ID_KEY as a phone book constant in a clean way

like Kotlin sealed classes the kolin compiler add some nice checks for enums (exhaustive) and they are designed
to provide clean readable code for pattern matching

see @Rolands answer here
[Kotlin: Using enums with when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54336074/kotlin-using-enums-with-when)

Comment: sure, my answer only relates to the code posted in the question, there are many possible solutions based on a given context

Answer (score 1):

try using interface :)

```
  companion object Constants {
/**
 * Collection of fields and values relative to phone books.
 */
interface PhoneBooks {
    /**
     * Field indicating the ID of a phone book.
     * Each phone book must have an unique ID.
     */
    const val PB_ID_KEY = "PB_ID"

    /**
     * Field indicating the status of phone book.
     */
    const val PB_STATUS_KEY = "PB_Status"

    /**
     * One of the possible [PB_STATUS_KEY] values, when the phone book is in indexing state
     * (usually at startup or in update phase).
     */
    const val PB_INDEXING = "Indexing"
    [...]
```