# when is exhaustive so else is redundant?

Tags: kotlin, appium

I am new to kotlin and I created a method that contains the when statement and IntelliJ suggesting me to remove the else branch.
I am not really sure why. Any idea why I need to remove the else branch here?
This is the code:

```
    companion object{
    @Synchronized fun getDriver(
        url: String,
        desiredCapabilities: DesiredCapabilities,
        mobilePlatform: MobilePlatform)
        : AppiumDriver<WebElement> =
        when(mobilePlatform){
            MobilePlatform.ANDROID -> AndroidDriver<WebElement>(URL(url), desiredCapabilities)
            MobilePlatform.IOS -> IOSDriver<WebElement>(URL(url), desiredCapabilities)
            else -> throw RuntimeException("Cannot get the driver")
        }
}
```

Comment: If `MobilePlatform` is a enum and it doesn't have any values except `ANDROID` and `IOS`, you don't need `else` branch.

Answer (score 8):

When you have exhausted all possible options of `when` there is no reason to have an else branch. This has the added advantage that you get a compiler error after adding elements to the enum without extending the `when`.

Answer (score 4):

In kotlin, `when` on a sealed class object doesn't require `else` if all possible inner cases are covered.

**Sample sealed class**:

```
sealed class A {
 object B: A()
 object C: A()
}
```

Let the above be a sealed class then any `object` of class `A` (lets say `a`), can be used inside a when exhaustively(not necessarily) while returning

```
return when(a) {
  is A.B -> return something
  is A.C -> return something
} // no need of else here as all cases are covered.
```

There is one catch here, if you just need to check for one condition, let's say `is A.B` you can write an else. Also, please note that, you need **NOT** write exhaustive conditions/else if it's just a statement.

**Example below:**

```
some code ...
when(a) {
      is A.B -> do some task
}
more code ...
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Note that from [Kotlin 1.6](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/11/kotlin-1-6-0-is-released/#:~:text=Sealed%20(exhaustive)%20when,your%20own%20functions.%C2%A0)
non-exhaustive `when` *statement*s will emit a warning and from Kotlin 1.7 they will emit an error. See [the issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47709).

Answer (score 0):

To utilize **else** block you can try something like:

```
    enum class PaymentStatus(val value: Int) {
     PAID(1),
     UNPAID(2) 
 }

    fun f(x: Int) {
    val foo = when (x) {
        PaymentStatus.PAID.value -> "PAID"
        PaymentStatus.UNPAID.value -> "UNPAID"

        else -> throw IllegalStateException()
    }
}
```

**OR**

create factory method `create` in the `companion object` of `enum` class:

```
enum class PaymentStatus(val value: Int) {
    PAID(1),
    UNPAID(2);

    companion object {
        fun create(x: Int): PaymentStatus {
            return when (x) {
                1 -> PAID
                2 -> UNPAID
                else -> throw IllegalStateException()
            }
        }
    }
}

fun f(x: Int) {
    val foo = when (PaymentStatus.create(x)) {
        PaymentStatus.PAID -> "PAID"
        PaymentStatus.UNPAID -> "UNPAID"
    }
}
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54336074/kotlin-using-enums-with-when) more details